# S-Curve with % complete column on MS-Project

Tags: ms-project

Does anyone have any idea or could provide me with any insight about how to setup S-Curve graph based on "% complete" column ? This would be very helpful as I am stuck with this task for 2 days.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi KhalilG, welcome! Asking for links is off-topic (falls under software recommendations), but the question itself is ok. Feel free to make the right adjustments.

Comment: Did you try using the burndown report?

Answer (score 1):

Under the tab [Report], you can select the [Burndown] report. This report shows the amount of open and completed tasks. You can also include the "% Complete" line in the graph.
[image: Example of a burndown graph]